# Parsing UTC date retrieved from web service results in local date

Tags: java, android, date, utc

My goal is to simply retrieve the current UTC time from a web service and produce a Date for consumption. The trouble I am having is that anytime I use my SimpleDateFormatter to parse the date string I end up with the date in local time. I have spent a while researching solutions for this and nothing is working for me. This is my code and check out the attached image for debug values. Thanks anyone for your help.

```
        URL url = new URL("http://www.timeapi.org/utc/now");

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.connect();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        String timeStamp = response.toString(); // response is in this format 2015-09-19T01:09:35+01:00

        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
        formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        Date date = formatter.parse(timeStamp);

        return date;
```

[image]

Comment: Show your input data, output data, expected result, and time zone.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do here.  You do realize that java.util.Date objects don't have a timezone.  So if you do the parsing correctly, date.equals( date2 ) would be true.  

However, you reformat the date into a string without the timezone then reparse it using the local time parser.  So without preserving the time zone information, your reparsing is what is causing the problem.

Comment: I am parsing the response string which has the time zone in it. I have also tried setting the time zone to UTC for the formatter that is parsing the response date string with the time zone info. I am not sure how else to get the parser to use UTC time.

Comment: You keep saying you end up with the date in local time, how are you determining this?  What happens if you use your parser with inputs of the same instant of time, just with different time zones (e.g 08:00+1:00 vs 09:00+2:00)?

Comment: Ok, I see my mistake, I was giving the debugger output too much credit. It keeps spitting out "Mon Sep 21 12:01:00 PDT 2015" as the date value when in fact the date value is a long 1442889040000 and the debugger is just interpreting it into my local time zone. So the conversion is happening but it is always displayed in PDT. Rookie mistake.

Comment: @Nerves82 Not the debugger exactly, the `toString` method implementation. Please search StackOverflow before posting. This issue has been covered hundreds of times before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no any timezone information in `java.util.Date` object.
The only thing that a Date object contains is a number of milliseconds since the "epoch" - 1 January 1970, 00:00:00 UTC.

Your string is already contain timezone `+01:00` and `SimpleDateFormat` is successfully using it due to `Z` in `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ`. So your `date` object is **what you need**.

During debugging(your screenshot) you see date in your local time. Here is the source code of `Date.toString()`:

```
public String toString() {
    // TODO: equivalent to the following one-liner, though that's slower on stingray
    // at 476us versus 69us...
    //   return new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy").format(d, Locale.US);
    LocaleData localeData = LocaleData.get(Locale.US);
    TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(tz, Locale.US);
    cal.setTimeInMillis(milliseconds);
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    result.append(localeData.shortWeekdayNames[cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)]);
    result.append(' ');
    result.append(localeData.shortMonthNames[cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)]);
    result.append(' ');
    appendTwoDigits(result, cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    result.append(' ');
    appendTwoDigits(result, cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
    result.append(':');
    appendTwoDigits(result, cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
    result.append(':');
    appendTwoDigits(result, cal.get(Calendar.SECOND));
    result.append(' ');
    result.append(tz.getDisplayName(tz.inDaylightTime(this), TimeZone.SHORT, Locale.US));
    result.append(' ');
    result.append(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    return result.toString();
}
```

Next line

```
formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

works when you need to get String representation of your date in UTC (`DateFormat.format(Date date)`).